# How come an abstract base class in python can be instantiated?

Tags: python, oop, abstract-class, abc

It is very surprising to me that I can instantiate an abstract class in python:

```
from abc import ABC

class Duck(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

if __name__=="__main__":
    d = Duck("Bob")
    print(d.name)
```

The above code compiles just fine and prints out the expected result. Doesn't this sort of defeat the purpose of having an ABC?

Comment: If you have no abstract methods, what's the point of using an ABC?

Comment: Good point, but then it would be nice if the docs explicitly stated that the *combination* of `ABC` and `abstractmethod` is what makes a true abstract class in python.

Comment: It's explicitly stated in the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) (search for "_at least one method_"). And it's sort-of stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) too ("_...cannot be instantiated unless all of its abstract methods and properties are overridden_" - if there are no abstract methods, then it's actually true that all of them have been overridden)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have no abstract method, you will able to instantiate the class. if you have at least one, you will not. In code that would read like

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Duck(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @abstractmethod
    def implement_me(self):
        ...

if __name__=="__main__":
    d = Duck("Bob")
    print(d.name)

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Duck with abstract method implent_me
```

It is the combination of the ABC metaclass, and at least one abstractmethod that will lead to you not being able to instantiate a class. If you leave out one of the two, you will be able to do so.

Comment: Not true. I was able to compile your code no problem.

Comment: @user32882 no, this answer is correct. The above code *compiles* just fine, but throws that runtime error.

Comment: Never mind. You're right, adding an abstractmethod means the code won't run...